# Recognising Limits Question of $1^{\infty }$ form

Tags: limits

I have the solution to this question in which they solved it knowing the limit is in $1^{\infty }$. However, I am not able to see how it is of the form, could anyone please explain? $$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{a-1+\sqrt[n]{b}}{a}\right)^n$$ where a>0, b>0

Comment: The root tends to 1.

Comment: But no restrictions are not given, like what if b and n are 2 and 1 resp, then it wouldn't tend. Now I think the question is missing some info. This website seems to provide more info, but still no restriction to 'n'. https://www.toppr.com/ask/en-my/question/the-value-of-displaystyle-limnrightarrowinftyleftfraca1sqrtnbarightna0b0-is-equal-to/ If b were 2, n were 1 or 2  and a were 1 it wouldn't  tend to 1 right?

Comment: It is mentioned that n tends to $\infty$

Comment: Oh, really sorry. I am an idiot. Lol.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Claim: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{b} = 1$ for all $b>0$.

(Not very rigorous) proof: Let $x = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{b}$.  Then $x^n \to b$ as $n \to \infty$.  $x$ will be positive (or zero), since $\sqrt[n]b$ is positive for all $n$.  If $x<1$, then $x^n \to 0$.  If $x>1$, then $x^n \to \infty$.  So, granting that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{b}$ exists in the first place, it has to be $1$.

Comment: We could think of it like this too right? $b^{\frac{1}{n}}$ tends to 1 because n tends to infinity, thus $\frac{1}{n}$ would tend to 0, therefore it becomes 1, making the expression $\frac{a}{a}=1$ right?

Comment: Yep, that's also a sensible (and admittedly much cleaner) approach.